# Maximo Anywhere - Performance tuning

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (WorkExecution app).

My requirement is, In the worklog execution view I wanted to show and hide nearly 400 fields based on some condition.

Let's assume there is 100 fields, based on some condition I have to show the 25 fields, based on some other condition , I have to show the other 50 fields like that.I have done the container based field hide and show.

The issue is, When I transit from workOrder details view to worklog view, It is taking some time.Kindly help me to tune the performance worklog view.

Answer (score 0):

Fine tuning can be done by offline storage in Maximo Anywhere. First time you could download data and save it in offline db. Next time onwards, you can load from offline db. You could sync with server if you want fresh data.Hope this helps